# How to Add mediation network in AdMob?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, admob, mopub

I have already implemented Admob ads in my application now I want to know about How to add MoPub networks as a mediation network in Admob, For this I have already add MoPub framework and Mediation adopter but I can't get Ads from MoPub can you please suggest me if there is an any code/setting to enable it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using HeyZap SDK. The implementation is easier than using AdMob or MoPub.

https://www.heyzap.com